# SQL SERVER 2014 - Split String & Convert to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string

`1,2,3|5`

After Split with `|`  I have

`1,2,3`, `5`

Now I want to convert `1,2,3` to `INT`. How can I achieve this?

Following is my query

```
Declare @tmpReferContentRule = "1,2,3|5"
SELECT items 
FROM splitbystring(@tmpReferContentRule,'|') 
WHERE id = 1
```

I want to use it in

```
SELECT name 
FROM tmptable 
WHERE id in(SELECT items FROM splitbystring(@tmpReferContentRule,'|'))
```

<sub>`id` is type of integer</sub>

The above query throws an error

> 1,2,3 could not be converted to int.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Obviously not MySQL, so I removed that tag.

Comment: `1,2,3` doesn't fit in an `int`, so you'll have to parse it somehow. What is you expected result?

Comment: I want to use it in select name from tmptable where id in(SELECT items from splitbystring(@tmpReferContentRule,'|') where id=1) here id is int

Comment: @QuestionWarriors you need to remove comma before conversion

Comment: @QuestionWarriors: So did you get the solution ?

Comment: Why not use a datatype *designed* for holding multiple values? Not sure what `5` is here, but since you seem to have multiple "types" of data involved here, and they're not tabular, xml seems like an ideal choice. Rather than stuffing values into a string and then having to invent complex mechanisms to re-extract them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
Declare @tmpReferContentRule varchar(20) = '1,2,3|5'

;with cte
AS
(
    SELECT items as subitem from dbo.splitbystring(@tmpReferContentRule,'|')
)
SELECT name FROM tmptable WHERE id IN 
(
    SELECT t.items FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT * from dbo.splitbystring (subitem,',')) t
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Krishnraj , I got solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this methods

```
select name from tmptable as t1 inner join (@tmpReferContentRule,'|') as t2 on 
','+t2.items+',' like '%,'+cast(t1.id as varchar(10)+',%' 
where t2.id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that string into table with the help of xml:

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(10) = '1,2,3|5',
        @xml xml

SELECT @xml = CAST('<r><a>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@string,',','</a><a>'),'|','</a><b>') +'</b></r>'  as xml)

SELECT  t.v.value('.','int') as id
FROM @xml.nodes('/r/a') as t(v)
```

Output:

```
id
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have been already using a split string function 
I have a similar [split string sql function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx), I used it as follows twice in your script

```
Declare @tmpReferContentRule varchar(max) = '1,2,3|5'

SELECT *
FROM Table1 t
inner join (
    select 
        s2.val 
    from dbo.Split(@tmpReferContentRule,'|') s1
    cross apply dbo.Split(s1.val,',') s2
    WHERE 
        s1.id = 1
) s on t.id = s.val
```